# Cant adding chars in to ArrayList<Character>?

Tags: java, arrays, char, character

I'm having a troublesome time adding chars to a ArrayList < Character> 
as of now I have:

```
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
String s = "abcd";
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length()-1; i++) {
        chars.add(i, s.charAt(i));  
    }
```

but there seems to be a problem with adding the char to the list. Can anyone help?

```
chars.add(s.charAt(i));
```

doesnt work for me either it keeps saying char is not applicable for the ArrayList

Comment: chars.add(s.charAt(i));

Comment: Please paste the whole code so we can see your `s` variable.

Comment: What is the type of `s`?

Comment: By any chance did you write your own `Character` class in the same package?

Comment: @VGR No I did not i wrote the main method thats all

Comment: @desiigner It works fine for me, what IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this you should be good.

**Code:**

```
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
   s = "abcd";
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            chars.add(s.charAt(i));  
        }
```

Comment: That won’t compile.  String has no public `length` field, only a `length()` method.

Comment: Also, the original works anyway... there's info missing in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert your string into character array list, try below:

```
String s = "abc";
char[] c = s.toCharArray();
Arraylist<Character> chars = Arrays.asList(c);
```

Or you can do it in one line if you want:

```
Arraylist<Character> chars = Arrays.asList("abc".toCharArray());
```

Basically, `Arrays.asList()` would return a list which maintains **the same order** of your arrays. So when you convert your String to a character array and turn it into a list by using Arrays.asList is same as you do `chars.add(i, s.charAt(i));`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to do it in Java 8 which is probably cleaner:

```
String s = "a";
List<Character> c = 
        s.chars()
        .mapToObj(x->Character.valueOf((char) x))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That is not cleaner.